# What's the limit of the sum as n tends to inifinty

Tags: integration, limits

The problem is to find $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k}\frac{1}{n^{k}(k+3)}$$ What i did is as follows: Let $$\sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k}\frac{x^{k+3}}{n^{k}(k+3)}=F(x)$$ Then we want to find $F(1)$. We have that $$F'(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k}\frac{x^{k+2}}{n^{k}}=\frac{x^2}{n^n}\sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k}x^kn^{n-k}=\frac{x^2(x+n)^n}{n^n}\implies F(1)=F(0)+\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^2(x+n)^n}{n^n}dx$$ Now I can get that $F(0)=0$ and $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^2(x+n)^n}{n^n}dx=\frac{(n+1)(n^2+n+2)(1+\frac{1}{n})^{n}-2n^3}{(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)}$ by integration by parts, and then evaluating the limit is easy. Or we can do as $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}F(1)=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^2(x+n)^n}{n^n}dx=\int_{0}^{1} \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} x^2(1+\frac{x}{n})^n=\int_{0}^{1}x^2e^x=e-2$$ But is there a better(and easier as well as quicker) method?

Comment: OP provides two nice solutions for $e-2$, and [Mathematica also agrees](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Sum%5BBinomial%5Bn%2C+k%5D+1%2Fn%5Ek%2F%28k%2B3%29%2C+%7Bk%2C+0%2C+n%7D%5D+as+n+to+infty). @DavidG.Stork

Comment: @angryavian:  You are correct.  (I put in the wrong lower-limit in the sum.)

Comment: This is a nice way to do it (+1)